# I have implemented MVVM pattern in wpf. But the result doesnt showed in the view. Can some one please help me?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, async-await

With  getAllCars() function i get all cars from a bckend webapi and I save them in ObservableCollection Cars. When I run the application it doest show any data.I dont know why the data are not showed  please any one to help?...............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

### MainWindow.xaml

[image of window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEwwZ.png)

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CarsUIWpfApp"
        xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:CarsUIWpfApp.ViewModels" x:Class="CarsUIWpfApp.MainWindow"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

        <ListView Margin="10" Name="carsList" ItemsSource="{Binding Cars}">
            <ListView.DataContext>
                <ViewModels:CarViewModel/>
            </ListView.DataContext>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="CarBrand" Width="auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding CarBrand}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="CarModel" Width="auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding CarModel}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="CarVin" Width="auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding CarVin}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Color" Width="auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Color}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

### MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window

    {

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

### CarViewModel

```
class CarViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private const string path = "https://localhost:44363/api/Cars";
   private ObservableCollection<Car> cars = new ObservableCollection<Car>();


    public CarViewModel()
    {
        LoadCars();
    }
    public ObservableCollection<Car> Cars
    {
        get { return cars; }
        set { SetProperty<ObservableCollection<Car>>(ref cars, value);
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public async void LoadCars()
    {
        Cars = await getAllCars();
    }

    public async Task<ObservableCollection<Car>> getAllCars()
    {
        

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(path);

            cars = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ObservableCollection<Car>>();
            return cars;
        }

    }

}
```

[Debuging image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8mFR.png)

Comment: Using the debugger, did you verify that the Cars collection contains the expected data when LoadCars completed?

Comment: Yes I have already checked it and it has the expected data

Comment: [Avoid async void](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void). It is intended for event handlers. Is the `LoadCars` method an event handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must not declare and call an `async void` method in a view model.

Declare it as `async Task`

```
public async Task LoadCars()
{
    Cars = await getAllCars();
}
```

and remove the call from the view model constructor, or remove the entire CarViewModel constructor.

Then in the view, move the DataContext assignment to the MainWindow and attach an async `Loaded` event handler:

```
<Window ... Loaded="WindowLoaded">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <ViewModels:CarViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    ...
</Window>
```

with this handler method in MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
private async void WindowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await ((CarViewModel)DataContext).LoadCars();
}
```

---

Also be aware that `Cars` does not need to be an ObservableCollection as long as you only ever create and assign complete collections, and never add or remove element from an existing Cars collection.

Comment: I have test it but it does not work any idea ?

Comment: You should debug your application to see step by step what it is doing. Is the LoadCars method called? Does it set the Cars property to a non-empty collection? Are there any data binding error messages in the Output Window in Visual Studio when you debug the application?

Comment: Now it worked Thanks alot . I have it working with your fix and added local variabele ObservableCollection<Car> cars1 = new ObservableCollection<Car>(); to getAllCars().

Comment: Can you please explain this code. The casting part.
    await ((CarViewModel)DataContext).LoadCars();

Comment: Not sure what to explain. The DataContext holds a CarViewModel object. In order to access the object's properties or methods, you have to cast it to the proper type.

Answer (score -1):

```
<ListView.DataContext>
      <ViewModels:CarViewModel/>
</ListView.DataContext>
```

doing this means that the listview has this **viewModel** as data context but in your items source you binded to the cars collection so the solution is to do so:

```
<Window.DataContext>
      <ViewModels:CarViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

Comment: Binding the ItemsSource would obviously also work if you set ListView.DataContext. Any Binding without an explicitly specified source object goes against the current DataContext of the target element.

Comment: I have tested it but it doesnot work any idea why ? @Mohamed Elhakim

Comment: Tested what? The difference between assigning both DataContexts in an otherwise working program?

Comment: could you send me the solution to fix it ?